# Installing 19.10 from usb but not appearing on grub

Tags: system-installation, usb

Per a video I found online, I have used the Etcher program in order to bring an ISO file of Ubuntu 19.10 onto a USB. I plugged the USB into my computer and restarted, and hit the boot menu button F11.

Three options come up:

- ubuntu (this takes me to my ubuntu on one of my hard drives)
- Windows Boot Manager (this actually takes me to my Windows, on another hard drive)
- Enter Setup

I can make my way into the GNU Grub screen, but all I see are four options (Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, Windows Boot Manager, and System setup). None of them are "Try Ubuntu without installing" or "Install Ubuntu" like I've seen on other videos.

I would definitely appreciate any leads from people here.

Comment: I would tend to follow official documentation rather than *unknown* videos, currently I'd guess you didn't write it correct, so I'll offer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-ubuntu/14011
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows/14020
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-macos/14016  Also useful is to verify ISO before write to media https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and then validation of write https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck (CD=any media used)

Comment: From the link for "Also useful is to verify ISO before write to media" I reach the sixth step "Check the ISO" but the command doesn't yield any results. This suggests that the ISO file is not okay, but I (a) made sure that the sha* files are all in my Downloads folder, along with the ISO, and (b) redownloaded the ISO file from the Ubuntu website after failing the command. Not sure where to move from here...

Comment: Actually - I was just able to get the sixth step to work, so I was able to verify the ISO. I think the problem I'm now is that I'm not able to reach any step that remotely looks like the "validation of write" step because that also looks like where I would be able to install Ubuntu.

Comment: You verify the *write to install media* with the "*Check disk for defects*" option, it's referred to as CD in some documentation, as I ~stated in first comment, CD/disk refers to any install media be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/etc; you boot the media and select the option (how it appears varies on your UEFI/BIOS/firmware setup, it maybe just a keyboard-in-rectangle or person-in-circle and requires a quick key for menu to appear; same media booted in another box will work differently as machine firmware dictates how it operates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Boot Live USB using grub from Internal Drive

I created a Live Ubuntu 19.10 USB using balenaEtcher.

I booted that Live USB by adding the following menuentry to my internal drive's grub menu:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu - flash drive" {
 search --set=root --fs-uuid xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   ($root)/casper/vmlinuz$casper_flavour  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed quiet splash  ---
    initrd  ($root)/casper/initrd$casper_flavour
}
```

Where xxxx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx is the UUID of the Live USB.

Comment: @rpickmans You are welcome, The menuentry is based on mkusb's method for booting ISO9660 files. I an still looking for a way to set root without using UUID.